# Show Preferred DNS and Alternate DNS on a label

Tags: c#, dns, network-interface

I want to be able to show what the current preferred DNS and Alternate DNS is through a label.

How would I do this?

I've looked into it and it seems I have to use

ManagementObjectSearcher? Using WMI?

Something like?

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter Where AdapterType='DnsForestName'");
foreach (ManagementObject mo in mos.Get())
{
    label1.Text = mos.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Do you care about which connection you get the DNS addresses for, e.g. cable or WiFi?

Comment: Yes I want the preferred DNS or Alternative DNS

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the machine on which the code will run will only have one network interface? If there can be more than 1 network interfaces, first question is, what is your criteria for selecting the right network interface?

Comment: Yes only 1 network interface, however if it does have two pick the local area connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at following - `IPInterfaceProperties.DnsAddresses` Property

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ipinterfaceproperties.dnsaddresses(v=vs.110).aspx

The documentation has a nice example of how you can enumerate all network interfaces, and their DNS IP addresses.. but like I said in my comment to your question.. if you have more than one network interface, you have to define criteria for choosing the one you are interested in..

Note that I am not 100% sure that the order in which this property returns DnsAddresses, is primary Dns, followed by 0 or more secondary.. I am guessing that is the case, but there is no documentation that I know of, which will confirm that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do what I wanted with this code.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NetworkInterface[] adapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        foreach (NetworkInterface adapter in adapters)
        {

            IPInterfaceProperties adapterProperties = adapter.GetIPProperties();
            IPAddressCollection dnsServers = adapterProperties.DnsAddresses;
            if (dnsServers.Count > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(adapter.Description);
                foreach (IPAddress dns in dnsServers)
                {
                    label4.Text = dns.ToString();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```